# Is it possible to breed pals that can produce alphas or other shinies?

Tags: palworld

Trying to breed some strong pals and any passive skill can be passed to the eggs and pal within. So I can have a pal with the **Lucky** passive skill by breeding a shiny with another, but it doesn't keep the shiny status.

Is it possible to produce an egg that produces an alpha or shiny pal?